# Email to Case Enabling

Tags: lightning, service-cloud-console

My org doesn't have **email to case enabled** and currently Form Assembly is being  used to capture cases from our company's website into salesforce.

There's a requirement where service cloud end users need to be able to select a from email address while sending an email to customers.
In order to get this requirement done...

As per my research online I found that email action button on case record will only be available if we enable email to case.

In such scenario if i enable Email to case Functionality and do not make the necessary settings for it.

will it effect the form assembly case capturing process?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably not turn email to case on if you don't intend to fully utilize it.

Instead, I would make a VF page (classic) or component (lightening) that can be used to send emails and save those emails as activities. You could easily add a pick-list of org wide email addresses to select as the from address in this case.

This would also match the other existing email functionality in SFDC as emails sent from other objects such as contacts are stored as activities.

Comment: Instead of a VF page (classic) or component (lightening) is there any other way to achieve this as i'm poor at coding.

Comment: Your question above is something that you are capable of testing on your own in a sandbox. My advice if you can't code to do it correctly then you should test thoroughly before attempting to implement email to case.